# Manually adjusting h2o glm coefficients for h2o.predict

Tags: r, h2o, glm

I'm trying to manually update some of the coefficients my H2O GLM produces for sparse segments. Regularisation is not an option unfortunately.

I'm trying to use GLMs using the H2O package in R to model amounts using several predictor variables. On some of the sparse predictors, I end up with inconsistent coefficients which I could manually update to consistent values in the object in base R. With this I could use the predict function quite neatly.

However, when I update them in H2O the h2o.predict function ignores the new coefficients and solves as per the original values. Is there another way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Dropping the variables is not an option.

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

insurance <- h2o.importFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/glm_test/insurance.csv")

predictors <- colnames(insurance)[1:4]
response <- 'Claims'

insurance['Group'] <- as.factor(insurance['Group'])
insurance['Age'] <- as.factor(insurance['Age'])

head(insurance)

claims.glm<-h2o.glm(family="tweedie",x=predictors,y=response, training_frame = insurance, lambda=0, compute_p_values = TRUE)
print(claims.glm)

#sample row for members age>35 for testing
sample<-insurance[4,]

sample

h2o.predict(claims.glm,sample)

#change Age>35 coefficient values in the model to 15 from 9.82 
claims.glm@model$coefficients_table[7,2]=15
claims.glm@model$coefficients[7]=15

#same predict & stderr as before
h2o.predict(claims.glm,sample)
```

Comment: A model reflects what is inside your data. It is not really ethical to modify the results of the model manually when the results are not what you expected. Maybe you should look in more details the reason of this output. Is the model adapted to your question ? Do you data support the hypotheses below glm construction ? What makes you think the model is wrong? Please do not try to modify manually a model output.

Comment: I appreciate what you’re saying and know the model is ‘correct’ but there are both commercial and regulatory constraints which mean i can’t use a model as is.